# Need Nav to stay right under header, fixed, without content overlap

Tags: html, css

I just recently fixed, thanks to you guys, how to get my header to not overlap my content when the size of page changes. Now, I was told to group my nav bar, with my h1 header, so that they can be in a fixed position together, but when I do that, it messes everything up. So now I'm looking to get some help into making my nav bar stay right under my header in a fixed position without overlapping content. It can be seen when you view my website, in a full page, how I want it. You can also see how the nav bar gets messed up when you change the size of the webpage.

first of my webpage is hosted here: https://knox-enterprise-inc.herokuapp.com/About.html

second here is my code for this page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
            <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <title> Knox Enterprises Inc.</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <h1>Knox Enterprises Inc.</h1>
                <div class="nav">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    <a href="About.html">About</a>
                    <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="home">
                    <div class="home-pictures">
                        <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/14o91c1.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                        <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2rpzh3p.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="home-pictures2">
                        <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/rswqoy.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                        <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/2lm8bdg.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="home-description">
                        <ul>
                            <h5>Riveredge, NJ</h5>
                            <h5>Date Completed: June 2014</h5>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="home">
                    <div class="home-pictures">
                        <img src="home_5.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                        <img src="home_6.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="home-pictures2">
                        <img src="home_7.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                        <img src="home_8.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="home-description">
                        <ul>
                            <h5>Teaneck, NJ</h5>
                            <h5>Date Completed: March 2015</h5>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="home">
                    <div class="home-pictures">
                        <img src="home_9.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                        <img src="home_10.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="home-pictures2">
                        <img src="home_11.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                        <img src="home_12.jpg" width="300px" height="225px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="home-description">
                        <ul>
                            <h5>Tenafly, NJ</h5>
                            <h5>Date Completed: August 2016</h5>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </body>
    </html>
```

css:

```
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-image:url("backround.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
    header {
        height: 220px;
    }
    #about-header{
        height: 100px;
    }
    #contact-header{
        height: 100px;
    }
    /*Knox Header*/
    h1 {
        position: fixed;
        top: -40px;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Georgia;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
        background-image: url("header.jpg");
        font-size: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
        border-top: 5px solid orange;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    /*Nav Menu/Home Page*/
    .nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 78px;
        background-image:#606060;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
    .nav a {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        background-color:black;
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-right: 2px solid orange;
        border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
        border-top: 2px solid orange;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
    .nav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
        }
    .home {
        text-align:center;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    .home-pictures, .home-pictures2{
        height:auto;
        width:auto;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .home img {
        border: 1px solid white;
        }
    .home-description {
        line-height: 0px;
        color: white;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 18px;
        }
    /*About Page*/
    .about, .about-description {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: helvetica;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
    .about-description {
        padding-top:100px;
    }
    .about-description p {
        font-family: helvetica;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 40%;
        color:white;
    }
    .about img {
        position: relative;
        top: 80px;
        margin-left:0 auto;
        margin-right:0 auto;
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    #last{
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .contact {
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:125px;
        color:white;
        font-family: helvetica; 
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    #phone-contact img{
        border-radius:100%;
    }
    #email-contact img{
        border-radius: 30%;
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the markup supplied is terribly invalid and anything to make it work is purely a hack or luck.

Comment: I supplemented the code, because I didn't want to post it all because it was irrelevant to the problem. I've fixed it to show all the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main problem that your `position: fixed` is on your `<h1>` tag instead of your header itself. To rectify this, first shift **all** of your `h1` styling to `#about-header` instead:

```
#about-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
  border-top: 5px solid orange;
}
```

Next, remove the pre-existing heights of `100px` and `220px` in `#about-header` and `header` respectively. These are set on lines 10 and 7 of `style.css` respectively.

Also remove `top: -40px`, and lower the `font-size` to `0.9em` (you may want a media query to modify that font at different sizes).

Finally, you need to make use of [**z-index**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) so that your header appears **on top** of any content that it scrolls over:

```
#about-header {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Your final `#about-header` should end up as:

```
#about-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
  background-image: url(header.jpg);
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
  border-top: 5px solid orange;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This will cause the sub-header to 'attach` to main header for both desktops and mobiles, and both headers will overlap all other content on all resolutions.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Well, my question was a 2 parter, so you solved 1 part, but I need to get the other thing solved as well, so I edited the page to specify towards that question. I will marked it as solved soon after.

Comment: What is the second part of your question? As far as I can tell, you're only asking how you can have your fixed header not overlap your page content? I've answered how to do that (so I'm not sure why this answer deserves a down-vote), and am happy to help with any other problem you may have, but you'll need to clearly specify exactly what that problem is.

Comment: if you look at my website, given the link, when you make the webpage smaller, the navigation bar moves and overlaps the header. When you look at my website from a full window, you can see the location of the nav bar, right under the header. I'm trying to find a way to get that to stay there when the web page window is changed in size.

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer, I think it was that other guy.

Comment: I've fixed up my answer to cover responsiveness :)

Comment: You are a dream come true. Thank you for the help! worked perfectly.